# Not Getting Email using Gmail smtp on live server Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, gmail

I am on Laravel 5.6 and my application working well.
I am using Gmail SMTP for mail services.

here is my .env file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I have already Turned ON **Less secure apps** in Gmail also turned ON **2 step verification**.

From localhost, the mail system working like charm and I am getting all emails from Gmail SMTP.

But From Live Server, I am not getting any Emails and even there is no error popup.

My Host is a **000webhost** free account because I am testing my Application.
so I read forums in 000webhost and change "SET MX RECORD " to "GOOGLE'S MX RECORD".

Now I am getting this error while sending any mail.

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1
>   Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError k142sm4568022ywa.67 -
>   gsmtp "

Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please set ```MAIL_PASSWORD``` as GoogleAppPassword

Comment: I have already set the password as GoogleAppPassword. In localhost, mail working fine but the problem is on the live server.

Comment: Not sure, May be its your server problem

Comment: Does anybody know that 000webhost allow smtp for free account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing your `config/mail.php` to your current credentials:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'username@gmail.com'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', 'password'),
```

Comment: yes, I changed it but still getting the same error.

Comment: how about changing your mail driver to `sendmail`?

Comment: i changed as you told but new error pop up saying "proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons"

Comment: you can disable it in your `php.ini` file `disable_functions = proc_open`

Comment: hey, I got a solution, i were using 'username' => env('username@gmail.com') instead of 'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'username@gmail.com'),  Thanks Man!

Answer (score 0):

Please allow access to less secure app from your google account following these steps:

> 1. Go to your [Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/).
> 2. On the left navigation panel, click Security.
> 3. On the bottom of the page, in the Less secure app access panel, click Turn on access.

If you don't see this setting, your administrator might have turned off less secure app account access.

[image: Google less secure app enable option]